# How to retrieve user avatar from a Trello API?

Tags: javascript, api, hash, trello, avatar

trello API gives only hashes, such as `avatarHash`, `gravatarHash`, `uploadedAvatarHash` etc. Is there any way to retrieve an image url from these hashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this hash you can retrieve an image by url: http://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/${avatarHash}/50.png

Comment: the `/170.png` size is also publicly available.

Comment: From the look of things the valid sizes (the part before `.png`) are: `30`, `50`, `170` and `original`.

Comment: Works if I spare the dollar sign. Thank you!

Comment: As of 2020-05-03, trello-avatars returns 403 for everything I try. Looks like gravatarHash may be the only way to get this now.

Comment: ...and I see that won't work unless you can lowercase md5 the individuals email for the gravatarHash (≠ Trello avatarHash). Solution: Replace 403'ing `https://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/{avatarHash}/30.png` with `https://trello-members.s3.amazonaws.com/{id}/{avatarHash}/30.png`. Means you'll need to have access to user/member `id`, but that should be with same info that `avatarHash` is returned.

Answer (score 5):

Trello uses Gravatar, so the hash you're getting back relates directly to that.

Base URL would be: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/

You can add on jpg and size between 1 and 512.

An example:

http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ [the hash here] .jpg?s=80

Will give back 80px avatar

```
function get_gravatar(hash, size) {           
    var size = size || 80;

    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hash + '.jpg?s=' + size;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, my friend! I knew that, but somehow couldn't figure out that I must add `.jpg` and size. Without these parameters it won't work. I found another solution for this issue: there is another hash `avatarHash` which differs from `gravatarHash`. Using this hash you can retrieve an image by url: `http://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/${avatarHash}/50.png` as well

Comment: I think the @mcmxc comment should be the answer. With Gravatar I got the wrong image, but with the amazonaws URL I got the correct one. (Or update this answer)

Comment: As of 2020-05-03, trello-avatars returns 403 for everything I try. Looks like gravatarHash may be the only way to get this now.

Comment: ...and I see that won't work unless you can lowercase md5 the individuals email for the gravatarHash (≠ Trello avatarHash). Solution: Replace 403'ing `https://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/{avatarHash}/30.png` with `https://trello-members.s3.amazonaws.com/{id}/{avatarHash}/30.png`. Means you'll need to have access to user/member `id`, but that should be with same info that `avatarHash` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

As at 14 July 2020 the correct URL path is as follows:

```
https://trello-members.s3.amazonaws.com/{member.id}/{member.avatarHash}/{size}.png
```

Note: this doesn't seem to work any arbitrary size value, however it does work for size = 170.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, as of 2020-05-05, both these answers don’t work.

1. `gravatarHash` solution works to get an avatar from Gravatar, but I’m not sure that solution ever worked as stated from the Trello API’s returned `avatarHash`, as the Trello API returns an opaque `avatarHash` which is NOT the same as a `gravatarHash`. According to [Gravatar APis](https://www.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/) they are a trimmed, lowercased, MD5’ed email address. So `gravatarHash` ≠ Trello `avatarHash`.
2. `https://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/{avatarHash}/50.png` now 403s. Trello devs made a change.

New solution:
Use `https://trello-members.s3.amazonaws.com/{id}/{avatarHash}/50.png`

Where `{id}` is the member/user id and `{avatarHash}` is the same retrieved from the Trello API. That same API allows you to specify returning `id` as well, so add that to the list of fields with the API call.

In validating by looking at avatars on Trello.com they do, in fact, only seem to use this `trello-members` URL.

This is returned in the same data response if you add the field `avatarUrl`.

I have updated our Gmail-2-Trello Chrome Extension (https://g2t.pub/chrome) and it’s working correctly with this new pattern.